# react native how to know if a repo I am importing is a native module

Tags: react-native

my question might be a little bit silly or ambiguous since I am fairly new to react native.

I'm trying to use the following repository for my react-native project https://github.com/smekalka/react-native-universal-pedometer. I have noticed that the repo is implemented in `.java` with `platform folder` unlike the regular `.js` or `.ts` files I used to see. Is this repository considered `native module` as react native doc describe?

Or in general how I can tell the whatever lib I am using is a native module.

The project is previously tested are under the support of `expo-cli`. I experienced the error `null is not n object` while using this repo. If so, I am probably going to eject the expo-cli and rewrite my code so I can use and even create own native-module for full control, some core implementations that written in other languages or `expo-cli` does not support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `android` and `ios` directories in the repository contain the 'native' code used to implement the platform-specific hooks that the Javascript will be able to pick up. Expo is not able to use these native modules or native code so your assumption is correct; you will need to eject your app in order to use this module.

If your app is below version 0.60 of React Native, after installing the module you will need to run `react-native link react-native-universal-pedometer` to link the native code to the Javascript runtime. If you're above 0.60, it will link automatically when installed.

Comment: thx. Can you elaborate a little bit about what is defined as "visible" for Expo. 
Does it mean I have to use pure JavaScript in order to run expo-cli

Comment: Not an expert with Expo, but yes I believe Expo requires just JavaScript.